# Script R not executed correctly sometimes

Tags: r

i've a problem with R script. The script is sometimes executed correctly but others doesnt work.

This is the error message:

> Error in seq.default(min.alpha, max.alpha, length = length(colors)) : 
>   'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite Calls: plot ...
>   .performance.plot.canvas -> rev -> seq -> seq.default

Any idea?

Comment: Sometimes your code leads to trying to call `seq` using a missing (or infinite) value for the `from` argument, and sometimes it does not.

Answer (score 1):

try to debug your code using a method called browser() inside the function you have written.

```
a<- function(){
browser() // the execution will halt here and then you can see your values
}
```